# Transaction Log SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

All,

We often delete many rows from a table and even though we are using set rowcount 10000 most of the times we fill up the Transaction Log. Is there something to do to avoid this problem happening?

Thanks,

M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things you can do:

- you can set your [database's recovery model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189275.aspx) to `SIMPLE` - this will limit the amount of data being logged - that's only part of a fix, however
- you need to establish frequent [transaction log backups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179478.aspx) - especially just before and just after batch deletes.

This is really more of a sysadmin/DBA question, and thus you'll probably get more and more useful answers on http://serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0):

**before** and **after** deleting data; you can run this query to empty transaction log:

```
dump tran SAMPLE_DB with truncate_only
go
```

Comment: that only works up to SQL Server 2005 - from 2008 on, the "with truncate_only" option isn't available anymore

Comment: Let's not see that recommended for a production database